# Which Linux security mechanisms tied to file path and underlying block device

Tags: linux, security

Among the in-tree Linux security modules, [AKARI](https://akari.osdn.jp/index.html.en), any out-of-tree LSMs, and other existing kernel-based solutions, does there exist a way to protect files on the basis of their paths AND their underlying block device?

SELinux and SMACK use extended attributes to control access to files, but this suffers from the problem of a applying access control to a mounted filesystem that might originate from an image file or an external storage device if those files have the same extended attribute values that those LSMs' policies might use. AppArmor can control access on the basis of file paths, so this avoids the problem posed by mounts, but this control can be bypassed with bind mounts and hardlinks.

Any approach that requires limiting filesystem mounting abilities or masking the LSM context of a mounted external storage is too complicated or will inevitably leaves holes open in the case of any sort of containerization system. So, is there any security module or mechanism that can restrict access to files when given the files' underlying block device and the real pathname on the filesystem it originates from (i.e., not the "live" FS view with all its bind mounts and overmounts)?

Example: Protect the file/directory at path `/share/certs/certs.db` on filesystem on block device `X` (some identifier like a device number, `by-path` ID, World Wide Name, etc.) from modification.

Comment: With hard links, a file can have more than one "real pathname" within a single filesystem: this is a long-standing fact of Unix-style filesystems. The primary unique identifier of a file within a particular filesystem is classically the inode number, not the pathname. The name of a file is just a directory reference to a particular inode.

Comment: @telcoM I know about all of that and I didn't feel like making the post longer. The nature of hard links may not be relevant if one is using the file as a marker without regard to its content. A solution can determine the inode number and protect the file on the basis of that in addition to the path for all I care.